# Program wont execute Function c++

Tags: c++

My function wont be called. This function should work like it would ask for the name,username,password and balance of a certain member just like what it does in main.

```
void addMember(player p[], int max){
  int a;
  for(a=max-1;a==max;a++){
    putname(p,a);
    userN(p,a);
    passW(p,a);
    Bal(p,a);
    printf("\n");
   }
}

main(void){
    int max = 1, a,choice;
    player p[max];
    welcome();
    getch(); 
    system("cls");
    for(a=0;a<max;a++){
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t\tNOTE: DON''T LEAVE ANYTHING BLANK\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\t CUSTOMER %d\n", a+1);
        putname(p,a);
        userN(p,a);
        passW(p,a);
        Bal(p,a);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This loop `for(a=max-1;a==max;a++){/*...*/}` will loop exactly `0` times because `a == max` yields false the first time through the loop.

Comment: so what should I do with this loop?

Comment: Maybe copy from `main()`???? `for(a=0;a<max;a++){/*...*/}`

Comment: oh i got it dude so it shouldve been a != max right?

Comment: That could work -- I didn't check thoroughly :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a for loop

```
for(a=max-1;a==max;a++)
```

here you provided a condition a==max which will not be satisfied and the loop body will not getting executed and will not enter in the loop body even once. You have to look on your for loop condition, it should be appropriate.

Comment: the function worked when i changed the condition but the problem now is the variables. they are scattered o.o

Comment: You have declared an player array p but you are not using it properly inside the loop. accept the player pointer in the function and increment it each loop iteration to store properly player name,user and password and balance. Let me know if it answer your question or you are looking something else.